# Cannot use nullptr in Shared Library (Android, iOS) in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: android, c++, visual-studio-2015

I created a cross-platform **Shared Library (Android, iOS)** in Visual Studio 2015 but I got a compiler error *"use of undeclared identifier 'nullptr'"* when I add the following line in the cpp of the shared library and tried to compile the Android library:

```
void* p = nullptr;
```

That is quite strange since *nullptr* is a keyword since C++11.

What makes it even stranger is when I created a cross-platform **OpenGL ES2 Application (Android, iOS, Windows Universal)** and added that line again (in SimpleRenderer.cpp) and compiled the Android app, it got complied!

So I guess there should be a way to use *nullptr* (and I think there should be other problems as well) in the Android part of **Shared Library (Android, iOS)** since it works in **OpenGL ES2 Application (Android, iOS, Windows Universal)**. Probably some settings need to be adjusted. Does anyone know how to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found it! In project property window, go to C/C++ > Language and set **C++ Language Standard** to C++11.

Sorry for having asked a stupid question.